# Order of comparison in composite UNIQUE constraint in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm designing a database and have come across a performance related problem. Please note that we are still in the phase of designing not implementing so I can't test anything yet.

I have the following table structure

```
Events
----------------------
EventID      INT    PK
SourceID     INT    FK
TypeID       INT    FK
Date         DATETIME
```

The table is expected to contain tens of millions of entries. `SourceID` and `TypeID` both reference tables with at most hundreds of entries.
What I want is to have the tuple `(SourceID, TypeID, Date)` unique across the table. The question is: can I somehow specify which of the three columns will be used as the first to determine uniqueness when I would insert a new item in the table?
Because if the index compared the `Date` first, then the addition would be much faster, than if it for example used `TypeID` first, right? Or is this a wrong question altogether and I should trust the SQL server to optimize this itself?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying index created to support the unique constraint will have the same column order as defined by the constraint.